# jquery-ui tabs - using more than once on same page

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using jquery-ui to implement tabs.

However, I need to use it more than one on the same page.

but jquery uses the id "tabs" (as opposed to class or something), so it only works for the first instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you change the tabs prefix?

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ idPrefix: 'ui-tabs-primary' });
```

Other than that, it seemed to [work for me](http://jsbin.com/isece4/edit) out of the box.

Comment: I was missing a line of code, and your code helped me see my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs1").tabs();
    $("#tabs2").tabs();

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe not the best way, but I worked for two tabs

#### first tab

```
   $(function(){
     var options = {
 event:'mouseover',
 selected:0
     };
     $("#tabs").tabs(options);
   });

<div id="tabs">.....</div>
```

---

#### second tabs

```
$(function(){
     var options = {
 event:'mouseover',
 selected:0
     };
     $(".tabs").tabs(options);
   });
<div class="tabs">.....</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
    $("#tabs1, #tabs2").tabs();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
    $("#tabs1, #tabs2").tabs();
});
```

It works perfect! You can add the tabs you want.

```
$( "#tabs, #tabs1, #tabs2" ).tabs();
```

Thank you very much user3152277!